# How to change the a particular column as a row heading and make a matrix in pySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Sample of my dataframe is given below.

| id | Header One | value | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 30 |
| 1 | B | 5 | 40 |
| 2 | A | 12 | 50 |
| 2 | B | 5 | 60 |
| 3 | A | 14 | 70 |
| 3 | B | 10 | 80 |

I want to transform this into a matrix where rows correspond to the distinct id, and columns correspond to the distinct Header ones and entries of the matrix are the total values. Rows should be named as 1,2,3 and Columns should be named as A,B. Therefore a 3x2 matrix with entries as the total values. How do I do this?

The resultant output should be as follows,

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 40 |
| 2 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 70 | 80 |

I tried dropping columns and considering entries separately but did not work.

The resultant output should be as follows,

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 40 |
| 2 | 50 | 60 |
| 3 | 70 | 80 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical row-to-column problem, which is implemented using the spark `pivot` function.

```
df = df.groupBy('id').pivot('Header One').agg(F.sum('total'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```